# Custom azure function trigger and scaling

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Hi I'm trying to find information on how an azure function running on a consumption plan would scale with a custom trigger. This article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-plan-works - seems to imply theres a custom scaling implementation per trigger and does not have any explanation of how that works with custom triggers (if at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom triggers are not supported for Azure Functions. I think the main reason for that is indeed lack of Scaling Controller hooks.

Based on what is done in [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview), you might be able to define your own triggers which are based on other existing triggers (like Orchestration Trigger is based on Storage Queues) to add your specific semantics, but reuse the scaling logic.